# Memory leak on returning pointer

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am facing a memory leak condition in the following functions.

```
char * readdatafromfile(unsigned pageNumber) {
    char *buff = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * pagesize);
    lseek(fd, pagesize * (pageNumber), SEEK_SET);
    read(fd, buff, pagesize);

    return buff;
}
//Read from file
char * readfromfile(char *fname, int pageno) {
    char *buff = NULL;
    fd = searchinvector(fname);
    if (fd > 0)
        buff = readdatafromfile(pageno);
    else
        printf("\nINDEX is not opened\n");
    return buff;
}
```

I am trying to call the function the following way

```
char* root_buf = readfromfile(fname,pageno);
```

Can someone point to me where the memory leak occurs and how to overcome it.

***EDIT***

I do call free(root_buf); later. Forgot to mention that part. I believe this has to do with the fact that I am creating a pointer and returning it. Maybe the reference is caught in another pointer in the caller function.

Comment: You never call `free`. Thats why you have leak.

Comment: It seems you also have a filedescriptor leak. (or is fd a global variable?)

Comment: @wildplasser fd just helps me to store mutiple file descriptors in a vector. It is an integer variable.

Comment: There is one place in your code where there is allocated memory. So that is the only place where a leak can occur. Where does valgrind say you have a leak?

Comment: @Rasmus malloc in readdatafromfile()

Comment: If you are sure you call `free` on root_buf, in a place where it is quarenteed to be executed (not within an `if`-statement) then it should be fine. Does valgrind say definitely leak or possible leak? Can you post the code from call to readFromFile to the `free`?

Comment: @Rasmus Definitely lost. I call free() just before the function ends. It is in scope when i call free. I call it in a void function, no other termination possible to skip this free(). The code is too long by the way.

Comment: Solved - Reallocation of a different sort was happening. Had to free before that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory allocated using `malloc` are never freed again. 
If you do this from your call site:

```
char* root_buf = readfromfile(fname,pageno); 
// do stuff
free(root_buf);
```

It should solve the leak.

Answer (score 0):

You are using  malloc here.

```
char *buff = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * pagesize);
```

You need to free the memory after you have used it.

After you are done with root_buf and no longer need it:

```
free (root_buf);
```